# How to force browsers not to prompt save password dialog box - C#

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, browser, passwords, save

I have been searching for a problem for days bu I couldn’t find the solution and I decided to ask.

I am “internet banking” developer. Our internet banking is “.NET C# MVC application”. My country’s banking authority says “On internet banking login pages, browsers must never show "Save Password" dialog box and “user name & password” must definitely not be saved.”

Our password field in login.cshtml is :

@Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { autocomplete = "off", autoCompleteType = "disable", autocorrect = "off" })

This banking rule is valid for years. At first, we had used “autocomplete = "off"” It was OK but then browsers started to ignore that.

Then I put an invisible password input field before the real password input and browsers focused on this invisible field and “Save Password” dialog box hasn’t shown. It was OK for several years but browsers are smart and they always find and destroy these tricks. It doesn’t work now.

I searched Stackoverflow’s all related questions and the most efficient solution for me is making {autocomplete = "one-time-code"}

This is OK for Chrome, IE and Edge but not working for Firefox. Firefox  always shows “Save Password” dialog box.  I couldn’t find solution for Firefox.  I know there are hundreds of browsers including mobile but this 4 browsers are OK for me.

How could I force Firefox not to show “Save Password” dialog box for Html.PasswordFor input?

PS: It is OK for me to chang the "PasswordFor" field to "TextBoxFor" field and after every key pressed to that field, I could make the entered letter to "bullet" or "star" character not to be seen but I don't know how to do that. I can get help about that issue also..

Thanks & Regards

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable browser 'Save Password' functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32369/disable-browser-save-password-functionality)

Comment: Unluckily this does not seem very possible. "In most modern browsers, setting autocomplete to 'off' will not prevent a password manager from asking the user if they would like to save username and password information." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete#values

Comment: @Sinatr this answer is from 2008 and is about setting `autocomplete="off"`, which does not work (anymore).

Comment: `autocpmplete=off` and putting an invisible password field are old solutions and browsers aren't cheated by them anymore, unfortunately..

Comment: Don't know if this can be reliably done, but I would recommend not to do tricky things with JavaScript, because this could prevent the usage of password-managers as well. The security of a banking portal should/must include a 2FA anyway, so I would concentrate on all the other measures like CSP-header, correct SSL setup, and the like.